# Increase latitude by 1 degree for each given random latitude point

Tags: python

In my application db I have many latitudes from -90 to 90 degrees.

Each time, a random altitude point arrives to the app. When it happens I need to calculate two new points, one +1 degree another -1 degree, so I get the range of 2 degrees for the give latitude.

For example, given latitude is 44.6930962, then two new points would be 43.6930962 and 45.6930962. With this, I can select from database limited range of locations to make the application faster.

However, what happens when given latitude is very close to 90, 0, -90 ? What is the formula to always get correct two new points? Also, sometimes latitude is with - sometimes with +. But I need just one formula for all cases.

```
latitude = 45.6930962
latLess = 45.6930962 - 1
latMore = 45.6930962 +1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "correct new two points"? For example, for latitude=89.9 ( or -89.9), what are the correct points?

Comment: There isn't any formula which will add to latitude beyond 90N (or subtract beyond 90S). Your random number generator may be faulty if you aren't weighting by land area at that latitude (which, depending on language might look something like `(acos(1.0 - 2.0 * random()) * 2.0 - pi()) * 90.0 / pi())`). Buffering near the poles can generate strange shapes, which cross over to the antipodal longitude.

Comment: I dont need precise data. Simply I want to get some data that would limit records in big area like 200km latitude (my data is all over the world). So cutting data even in 6 parts would be helpful.  And later i do exact calculations for small area like 100km.

Comment: User enter some latitude and longitude. I want to restrict the data first only by latitude. Like he gives latitude = 45.6930962. I want to take then all records in approx 1 degree around or more . Or simply take all records in 100-1000 km distance of latitude. Then work further with data. It is because sql selects very fast compared to the program code.

Comment: One degree is at most 60 nautical miles (111.12km) at the Equator, but it could be as little as 1mm near a pole. If you really want to search based on area you can't skimp on the math.

Comment: If you just need a basic range of latitudes to search, you can just add a conditional statement to account for the limits of 90/-90.  `if point_latitude + 1 > 90:  latMore = 90  else:  latMore = point_latitude + 1` and `if point_latitude - 1 < -90:  latLess = -90  else:  latLess = point_latitude - 1`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need something like this:

```
l  = 45

latLess = l + 1 if l + 1 < 90 else 90
latMore = l - 1 if l - 1 > -90 else -90

print(latLess, latMore)
```

> for `0`  ->   `-1, 1`
> for `45` ->   `44, 46`
>
> for `89.9`  -> `88.9, 90`   -> (not `88.9, 90.9`)
> for `-89.9` -> `-90, -88.9` -> (not `-90.9, -88.9`)